# In .NET Core, What are the differences between HttpContext.SignOutAsync() and ControllerBase.SignOut()?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.2, ws-federation

I am currently implementing a signout method for our WsFederation in **.NET Core 2.2**. And I found these two methods:

1. ControllerBase.SignOut Method
2. AuthenticationHttpContextExtensions.SignOutAsync Method

I found these two answers:

1. [SignOut (LogOut) Error in AspNetCore 2.1 with WsFederation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52992707/signout-logout-error-in-aspnetcore-2-1-with-wsfederation)
2. [ASP.NET Core Identity 2.0 SignoutAsync is not logging out user if the user signed in with Google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46131517/asp-net-core-identity-2-0-signoutasync-is-not-logging-out-user-if-the-user-signe)

I also checked out the Microsoft documentation:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.signout?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ControllerBase_SignOut_System_String___
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.authenticationhttpcontextextensions.signoutasync?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Authentication_AuthenticationHttpContextExtensions_SignOutAsync_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_HttpContext_

Still don't have a clear answer.

Can anyone tell me what are the differences? and Which one I should use for signing out the authentication/WsFederation from the middleware I established in Startup.cs.

Thanks in advance!

T

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [source](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/affd7e00df310cdf53744ee22cd4631a414f6c05/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/SignOutResult.cs) for `SignoutResult` (`ControllerBase.Signout` returns a new `SignoutResult`), `ExecuteResultAsync` calls `SignOutAsync` on the `HttpContext`. The only difference might be that calling it on the `ControllerBase` results in a proper response being sent to the client.

Comment: Essentially they both should do the same thing. Logically though, returning the SignoutResult makes more sense.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I'll mark this as the answer. I dug a little deeper. Actually, the signout method from .net core won't do the work for our system. We have an extra layer (siteminder) that blocking the code from signing out.